# regex match word characters with only 1 space between any word

Tags: java, regex, string

I have a very specific username format and I cannot seem to accomplish it via regex

Here is my pattern:

`"\w([ ]{4,12})\w"`

The specifics to the format are as follows:

- Username must be greater than or equal to 4 characters but less than 13 characters
- Username may not contain spaces as the first or last character
- Username may not contain consecutive white space (or any kind of non-char space), e.g: `User  Name`
- Username may not contain any special characters, only word characters, numbers and spaces permitted
- There must be word characters before and after a space

My previous patterns aren't working properly, any guidance in the right direction would be great

Comment: What flavor of regex?  This makes a big difference in what elements we can suggest.

Comment: I am using the Java regex engine as specified by the [Pattern](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) class. @Monty Wild

Comment: @MontyWild Don't forget to double-blackslash character classes in string literals.

Comment: @DavidEhrmann I do use the double-escape when in the string literal, removed on here for readability sake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this? It uses negative lookahead to make sure any time it matches a space, it isn't followed by a space.

`\w(\w| (?! )){2,10}\w`

Comment: Perfect answer, contains all the attributes I needed. Thanks much!

Comment: I would use `\w(?:\w|\s(?!)\s){2,10}\w` no need to capture the group and also I wouldn't mix meta sequences with literals as it makes it harder to read.

Comment: `\w` also matches underscores (`_`), they may be considered to be special characters

Answer (score 0):

You would need a regex similar to the following:

```
[a-zA-Z0-9]((?!\s{2,})[a-zA-Z0-9 ]){2,10}[a-zA-Z0-9]
```

This is:

`[a-zA-Z0-9]`: Match any alphanumeric character,

and:

`(?!\s{2,})`: Negative lookhead for 2 or more whitespace characters

plus:

`[a-zA-Z0-9 ]`: Match any alphanumeric or space character:

`(` ... `){2,10}`: 2 to 10 times

`[a-zA-Z0-9]`: ending with any alphanumeric character.